# selecting multiple jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm saving some objects as variables like this:

```
var $var1 = $(".class1"),
    $var2 = $(".class2");
```

Normally I would select the same elements like this:

```
$(".class1, .class2");
```

But since they're already available as a variables, is it possible to select them somehow like this?

```
$($var1, $var2);
```

Every function I'm firing on such collection applies only to the first variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$var1.add($var2).dosomethig
```